# mongodb connection pool with authenticated connections in C++ driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I've read that the connection pool of the C++ driver doesn't work with authenticated connections ([article](http://craftycode.co.za/2013/12/10/mongodb-connection-pool-in-cpp/) from end of 2013).
Is this (still) true?

Comment: If nobody knows the answer to this question, maybe is a matter of using one of the examples in the article, trying to connect to a MongoDB configured with authentication using that ScopedDbConnection object and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [the documentation regarding the new C++ driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-26compat-and-legacy#changes-to-apis) (named "legacy"), it seems that the relevant classes has been removed:

> The ConnectionPool and ScopedDbConnection classes have been removed.

So the situation is even worse: not only the driver doesn't provide any mechanism for implement connections pools with authentication... it doesn't provide any pool connection mechanism at all :(

The rationale is detailed in [this issue at MongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-336):

> At this time, we have no plans to add pooling back into the legacy driver for the upcoming 1.0 release. It should be very straightforward to implement a simple pool for your application, and you will have one that does exactly what you want